# How to get repeated number's frequency in a column of a table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

good day.

Table 1

| ProductId | OrderId |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 7 |
| 12 | 12 |
| 13 | 13 |
| 14 | 13 |
| 15 | 13 |
| 16 | 14 |
| 17 | 14 |
| 18 | 14 |
| 19 | 14 |
| 20 | 14 |

Table 1 has 2 columns. One column is "ProductId", another is "OrderId". In OrderId, some order is unique ("7", "12") nut some orders are repeated (OrderId "13" repeated 3 times, OrderId "14" repeated 5 times). Now I want to get Table 2 which will indicate the repetition frequency.

I want to know, how many unique entries there, then how many 2 times repeated OrderId there, how many 3 times repeated OrderId there, and so on

Table 2

| Repeating__Order_Id | Order_Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |

Now, what will be the SQL query to get Table 2 from Table 1?

```
SELECT OrderId, COUNT(*) as Repeating_Order_Id
FROM Table 1
GROUP BY OrderId;
```

This code does not serve my purpose.

Comment: What's your MySQL version?

Comment: I am a beginner, and writing the query in Dbeaver 21.0.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the numbers for a given sequence of frequencies you will need a `nums` table to go along, like this one:

```
create temporary table nums (i int);
insert into nums VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

Then, this should do it:

```
select i,COALESCE(c2,0) cnt FROM nums LEFT JOIN
 ( select cnt, count(*) c2 FROM 
  ( select ord_id, count(*) cnt FROM tbl group by ord_id) 
  t1 group by cnt ) 
 t2 ON cnt=i
```

See demo here: [dbfidle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96fa49e0dc5ce81a3368c37c2bc34993)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT OrderId, COUNT(OrderId) as Repeating_Order_Id FROM Table 1 GROUP BY OrderId;
```

**Replace** COUNT(*) by COUNT(OrderId)

REF: https://qastack.fr/programming/3841295/sql-using-alias-in-group-by

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this query gives me which OrderId repeated how many times. I need to know in the opposite way. Like, how many unique entries there, then how many 2 times OrderId there, how many 3 times repeated OrderId there, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select cnt as repeating_order_id, count(*) as order_number
from (
  select product_id, count(*) as cnt
  from t
  group by product_id
) x
group by cnt
```